# Error loading files from Multiatlas in Phaser3

Tags: json, typescript, webpack, phaser-framework, texture-atlas

Trying to use the multiatlas feature in Phaser and TexturePacker.

Getting this error:

```
VM32201:1 GET http://localhost:8080/bg-sd.json 404 (Not Found)
Texture.js:250 Texture.frame missing: 1/1.png
```

The JSON file actually resides at `http://localhost:8080/dist/img/bg-sd.json` and I can browse to it. I can also browse to `http://localhost:8080/dist/img/bg-1-sd.png`.

I'm loading the atlas like:

```
    scene.load.multiatlas({
        key: 'bg-sd', 
        atlasURL: 'dist/img/bg-sd.json', 
        baseURL: 'dist/img'
    });
```

The `1/1.png` frame is also in the file:

```
{
    "textures": [
        {
            "image": "bg-1-sd.png",
            "format": "RGBA8888",
            "size": {
                "w": 1924,
                "h": 2039
            },
            "scale": 0.5,
            "frames": [
                {
                    "filename": "1/1.png",
                    "rotated": false,
                    "trimmed": false,
                    "sourceSize": {
                        "w": 960,
                        "h": 540
                    },
                    "spriteSourceSize": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "w": 960,
                        "h": 540
                    },
                    "frame": {
                        "x": 1,
                        "y": 1,
                        "w": 960,
                        "h": 540
                    }
                },
```

I've tried various combinations of the `path` and `baseURL` [settings](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html#multiatlas__anchor) but it will not load the file from `dist/img`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think providing both a `baseURL` and an `atlasURL` might be conflicting. The `baseURL` is attached in front of the `atlasURL` value so you're probably loading something like `dist/img/dist/img/bg-sd.json`.

Have you tried without the configuration object, like:

```
this.load.multiatlas('bd-sd', './dist/img/bg-sd.json');
```

Comment: This works, but only when I manually prepend the image path in the json file. TexturePacker seems to have a bug that the TexturePath property isn't used on mulitpack.

Comment: @AndrewGrothe could you share your edit in the json file?