# phaser 3 throws "Texture.frame missing:" warning and fails to load frame, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

**Note**: my code is already running and rendering the sprite

just one click to [play with](https://jsfiddle.net/shiqangpan/cx9a5v0p/9/)

---

I'm learning [a phaser3 loader example](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/blob/e5ec94a68a9393082d797645d0e830e2f6112bf1/public/src/textures/sprite%20sheet%20from%20atlas.js)

here is the code I wrote

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/';
    this.load.atlas('player', 'knight_atlas.png', 'knight_atlas.json');
  }
  create() {
    var player = this.add.sprite(80, 100, 'player', 0);
    player.setScale(.5);
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  pixelArt: true,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 },
    }
  },
  backgroundColor: 0x000000,
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine so far.

However, changing the `create()` as follows

```
  create() {
    var player = this.add.sprite(80, 100, 'player', 5);
    player.setScale(.5);
  }
```

doesn't load the frame as expected and throws a warning

> Texture.frame missing: 5

I compared the 'knight_atlas.json' file with [the one](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/blob/e5ec94a68a9393082d797645d0e830e2f6112bf1/public/assets/atlas/trimsheet/trimsheet.json) from the official example. I don't see the difference.

I also checked the [doc](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html) but didn't find a solution.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error loading files from Multiatlas in Phaser3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59238651/error-loading-files-from-multiatlas-in-phaser3)

Comment: @code in my opinion, the issue of the error is a different one, since wrong path don't have to do anything, with using a index instead of the key/filename of the atlas.

Comment: @yaojp the error has nothing to do with the path's, you must use the key/filename from the `atlas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the third parameter you would have to use the string (or Texture Object), in this case the `filename` from the atlas should work. Here the is [relevant documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html)

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/';
    this.load.atlas('player', 'knight_atlas.png', 'knight_atlas.json');
  }
  create() {
    var player = this.add.sprite(80, 100, 'player', 'Attack (3).png');
    player.setScale(.5);
    
    var player2 = this.add.sprite(240, 100, 'player', 'Idle10');
    player2.setScale(.5);
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  pixelArt: true,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 },
    }
  },
  backgroundColor: 0x000000,
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```